# Ubuntu 22.04 in Hyper-V and Nvidia 3080Ti - How do I use the NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

Novice user here

Installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS via the Windows 11 Hyper-V integration

Got enhanced session working via xrdp, and am currently using the desktop with no problems

Except I cannot get the NVIDIA drivers to work for better peformance!

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md

and ran
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-515 libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386`
with no failures and completed a reboot, but noticed nothing changed upon the reboot.  Loading the NVIDIA control panel inside the app panel showed no functionality, and sure enough I tried running `nvidia-smi` and it says it cannot communicate with the graphics driver.

What went wrong?

What steps am I missing?

Windows 11/NVIDIA 3080Ti

Comment: This is not really an Ubuntu question.  You should google which cards support GPU passthrough, and your 3080TI is not on the list I get.